# Options select in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, select

How I can manually enter the options of a select, I have been using the following:

```
<%= f.collection_select :establecimiento_id, Establecimiento.order(:nombre), :id, :nombre, include_blank: true %>
```

But that is used to select data from a table, I want to create one with the months, will it be necessary to create a table with the months or is there a way to enter in the code what I want?

Answer (score 0):

The second param (in your case `Establecimiento.order(:nombre)`) is the collection for your select. You can pass a array with pairs of values for `value` and `text` of that option. For instance, `[[1,"January"], [2,"February"] ]` and so on will give you the options with the month name, and the value that will be submitted will be the first one of the pair (in that case, the number of month, but could be the name anyway. It depends of what you want to achieve).

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: I got this: undefined method `nombre' for [1, "January"]:Array (I want to save the name "January")

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<%= f.collection_select :establecimiento_id, collection:[[1,"January"], [2,"February"] ], :id, :nombre, include_blank: true %>
```

I am not sure about the syntax but above answer gave it already away. You can pass options manually. Check API for collection_select:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

Comment: I got this error:syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC ...nuary"], [2,"February"] ], :id, :nombre, include_blank: true... ... ^